# Can you get access to a pages front matter (or other data) in a eleventy (11ty) plugin

Tags: plugins, eleventy

I'm creating (would like to create) an [eleventy (11ty)](http://11ty.dev) plugin that can automatically generate Open Graph images based on a pages data. So in the template:

```
---
generate_og_image: true
image_text: "text which will be baked into the image"
og_image_filename: some_file_name.jpg
---

#some markdown 
...
```

I can process each file in my `.eleventy.js` file via plugin using:

```js
module.exports = function (eleventyConfig) {
  eleventyConfig.addLinter("og-image-generator", function(content, inputPath, outputPath) {
    title = HOW_TO_ACCESS_TEMPLATE_FRONT_MATTER
    createImage(title)
  });
}
```

But only have access to the content,  inputPath and outputPath of the template.

How can I access the front matter data associated with the Template? Or is there a better way to go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question. As [@moritzlost](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3167371/moritzlost) mentioned it is not possible directly. I found this workaround.

`eleventyComputed` allows you to dynamically assign values to keys. It also allows you to call a custom [shortcode](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/shortcodes/).

You can pass whatever properties you like from the template into the shortcode. In this case `ogImageName` the image name, ogImageTemplate a template or background image and `text` which is the text to be written on that background.

You can even pass in other keys from your front matter and process them as you go.

```
---
layout: _main.njk
title: "Some title here"
eleventyComputed:
    ogImageName: "{% ogCreateImage { ogImageName: title | slug,  ogImageTemplate: 'page-blank.png', text: title } %}"
---
```

Then in `.eleventy.js` or a plugin:

```js
 eleventyConfig.addShortcode("ogCreateImage", function(props) {
      const imageName = props.ogImageName 
      const imageTemplate = props.ogImageTemplate 
      const imageText = props.text 
    
      console.log('-----------------ogCreateImage-----------------');
      console.log(`filename: ${imageName}`);
      console.log(`using template: ${imageTemplate}`);
      console.log(`with the text : ${imageText}`);

      // call  the image creation code — return filename with extension
      const imageNameWithExtension = createOGImage(imageName, imageTemplate, imageText) 

      return imageNameWithExtension
     });
```

Returning the final filename which you can use in your template.

Answer (score 1):

I've also come across this problem. I don't think what you're trying to do is possible at the moment. There are not many ways for a plugin to hook into the build step directly:

- Transforms
- Linters
- [Events](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/events/)

I think events would be the best solution. However, events also don't receive enough information to process a template in a structured way. [I've opened an issue regarding this on Github](https://github.com/11ty/eleventy/issues/1600). For your use-case, you'd need to get structured page data in this hook as well. Or eleventy would need to provide a build hook for each page. I suggest opening a new feature-request issue or adding a comment with your use-case to my issue above so those hooks can be implemented.

### Other solutions

Another solution that requires a bit more setup for the users of your plugin would be to add your functionality as a [filter](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/filters/) instead of an automatic script that's applied to every template. This means that the users of your plugin would need to add their own template which passes the relevant data to your filter. Of course this also gives more fine-control to the user, which may be beneficial.

I use a similar approach for my site [processwire.dev](https://processwire.dev):

1. A special template loops over all posts and generates an HTML file which is used as a template for the generated preview images. This template is processed by eleventy. ([source](https://github.com/MoritzLost/ProcessWireDev/blob/fdd537a8a9f923180444d13f445c39855f32a3b4/site/preview-images/preview-images.njk))
2. After the build step: I start a local server in the directory with the generated HTML files, open them using [puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer) and programmatically take a screenshot which is saved alongside the HTML templates. The HTML templates are then deleted.
3. This is integrated into the build step with a [custom script](https://github.com/MoritzLost/ProcessWireDev/blob/fdd537a8a9f923180444d13f445c39855f32a3b4/src/generate-preview-images.js) that is [executed after the eleventy build](https://github.com/MoritzLost/ProcessWireDev/blob/fdd537a8a9f923180444d13f445c39855f32a3b4/package.json#L18-L24).

I've published the script used to take screenshots with Puppeteer as an NPM package ([generate-preview-images](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generate-preview-images)), though it's very much still in alpha. But you can check the [source code on Github](https://github.com/MoritzLost/generate-preview-images) to see how it works, maybe it helps with your plugin.

Comment: Yeah found that it wasn't possible. Got a workaround (see below) using shortcodes instead of filters. I'm using https://www.npmjs.com/package/canvas instead of puppeteer so don't need the additional build step.